# encryption facility in lucene

Tags: java, encryption, lucene

Recently in my project i used lucene for duplicate search in our db and it is perfectly working.
But now there is requirement for encrypting lucene indexes and i was asked to look for encryption facility provided by lucene itself rather than using external libraries.

I just found LUCENE-2228 AES Encrypted Directory and made small POC.
Problem is that when i do re-indexing I get following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: File already Exists
    at org.apache.lucene.util.AESWriter.<init>(AESWriter.java:117)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.AESDirectory$AESIndexOutput.<init>
        (AESDirectory.java:187)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.AESDirectory.createOutput(AESDirectory.java:72)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.finishCommit(SegmentInfos.java:939)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.finishCommit(IndexWriter.java:3539)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.commitInternal(IndexWriter.java:3529)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.closeInternal(IndexWriter.java:1879)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.close(IndexWriter.java:1822)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.close(IndexWriter.java:1786)
    at org.apache.lucene.test.indexing.main(indexing.java:45)
```

**Here is my Code**:

```
public class indexing 
{
    private static final byte[] KEY = 
        new byte[] { 'T', 'h', 'e', 'B', 'e', 's', 't',
'S', 'e', 'c', 'r','e', 't', 'K', 'e', 'y' };
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {

        Directory INDEX_DIR = new AESDirectory(new File("index1"),KEY);

        Connection conn=null;

        SnowballAnalyzer analyzer=new SnowballAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30,"English");
        try
        {
           Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
           conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:///lucene", "abcd", "abcd");
           IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_34, analyzer);
           IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(INDEX_DIR, config);
           writer.deleteAll();
           //writer.flush();
           System.out.println("Indexing to directory '" + INDEX_DIR + "'...");
           long starttime=System.currentTimeMillis();
           indexDocs(writer, conn);
           writer.optimize();
           writer.close();
           long endtime=System.currentTimeMillis();
           long timetaken=TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(endtime - starttime,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
           System.out.println("Time taken to do indexing is "+timetaken+"ms");
        } 
        catch (Exception e)
        {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    static void indexDocs(IndexWriter writer, Connection conn) throws Exception 
    {
        //String sql = "select qid,question from tblquestions";
        String sql = "select qid,question from tblquestions";
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        stmt.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        Integer count = 0;
        while (rs.next())
        {
            count ++;
            Document d = new Document();
            d.add(new Field("qid", rs.getString("qid"), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
            d.add(new Field("question", rs.getString("question"), Field.Store.YES,  Field.Index.ANALYZED));
            writer.addDocument(d);
        }
        System.out.println("count: " + count);
    }
}
```

Can anybody help me solve this problem.
or
Give some idea about encryption of lucene indexes.

Comment: Which version of lucene are you using ? Did you get AESDirectory to work ?

Comment: Have you considered encrypting your entire filesystem?

Comment: Or, at least, mounting an encrypted FS/container/overlay at Lucene index directory?

Answer (score 0):

The patch is for version 3.1 and it seems you are using some other version of Lucene. Choose one of the following alternatives till a patch for your version is out (or write your own patch!)

1. Switch to Lucene 3.1
2. Use Windows NTFS encryption. Should be secure unless the unauthorized person knows how log in as the user that created the index.
3. Continue using TrueCrypt or other external encryption. This should be very safe but it requires the installation of TrueCrypt and administrative rights to install the encrypted drive.